# Do this method can blow off the 2006 mysql error

Tags: php, mysql-error-1064

Few days back i suddenly came up with getting empty result, I was surprised and then check out the mysql_error function and then got this 2006: Mysql server has gone away. The problem is that it doesn't comes everytime, but sometimes only for the same query.

I have checked out many questions here at stackoverflow as well as many blogs on the web, but I found no possible solution for this error

Today, I wrote this function for that and the error gones away,

```
$conn = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
    $db_select = mysql_select_db($this->dbName, $conn);

    for($i=0;mysql_error($conn) != 2006;$i++)
    {
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
        if($i > 10){break;}
    }
```

I wanna ask the professionals that if it it is the proper way of getting rid of this kinda situation or it is the wrong method for that

Comment: Query was so simple, not so tough:
1. SELECT * FROM hotels WHERE hotel_id = '$hid';

Comment: this is likely to be a MySQL config issue, have a look around at the connection settings

Comment: What type of connection settings?

Comment: have a look in your mysql.conf and make sure `wait_timeout` is large enough, try setting it to 600 seconds, then restart mysql service and see if the problem goes away

Comment: I have contacted my hosting provider & they said that we have our custom mysql config and we don't change it for a particular user... :(

Comment: is the result set of the query particularly large?

Comment: No a set of 6 columns, where 4 columns contains integer value and 2 columns contains 20-50 length string

Comment: Have you asked your hosting provider whether it is a common issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error will occurr when the MySQL server has been restarted / unavailable. It could be happening on a specific query if the query is causing some kind of problem (can't say more without knowing what the query does).

Either way, this error is valid and shouldn't be ignored. You need to find out WHY it is being raised in the first place.

You can use the [mysql_ping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-ping.php) function to check if the server is available before running a query rather than catching the error.

Comment: It can also happen if the connection idles for too long (MySQL will close the connection if it times out). This can happen in a PHP script if the script is waiting for something to happen or a resource to become available.